# How to customize a API in django-rest-framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

how can I customize a api with django-rest-framework?
If I need to have a function, it's not CRUD,  example I want statistic a count,
how can I do it?
and I can't find "customize api" in http://www.django-rest-framework.org/
Tell me what part of my watch

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [APIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#class-based-views). You will need to make `get`, `post`, etc. methods and in those you can return whatever you need.

Comment: how to write `urls.py`? Can not use `DefaultRouter()`?

Comment: Here is an example for `urls.py`:

`urlpatterns = [ url(r'^your_url$', your_view.as_view()), ]`